# Block Cipher Python unichr() output formatting Issues

Tags: python, encryption, ascii, block-cipher

I'm trying to write a python script that can encrypt and decrypt text using a block cipher, but I keep getting completely blank outputs. After trying to track down the source of the problem I realised that after I'd performed my XOR Bitwise Operation (a^b) my script couldn't convert the new ascii value into a character.

```
def blockcrypt(text,key):
    rawkeylist = rawintkey(key)
    textlist = asciitextlist(text)
    answer=''
    kli = 0
    for element in textlist:
        answer+=str(unichr(element^rawkeylist[kli]))
        kli+=1
        if kli==len(rawkeylist):
            kli=kli%len(rawkeylist)
    return answer
```

Where rawkeylist is the original key converted into a list of the ascii values (in decimal) for each character. And textlist is the text converted into a list of the decimal ascii values for each character. I've already used print to confirm that these are outputting the correct lists.

The problem is for several inputs I've tried no answer is produced. More importantly, by substituting print into various places I found that str(unichr(element^rawkeylist[kli]))
wasn't outputting anything after doing a bit of research into unichr I found that it actually outputs u'_____' (with _____ acting as a placeholder for whatever).

I could just not convert my ASCII values back to characters but that doesn't seem like the most innovative solution. I also am very doubtful of the effectiveness of using a string to add to my answer. Finally, I am simply recycling through the characters of my key when applying the cipher and after doing some research I heard of something called padding which I feel I should be using.

So um please help I guess.

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you focus on one specific problem (so in this case, don't worry about padding for now) and tell us exactly what behavior you want.

Comment: What block cipher is this? It seems a One Time Pad (OTP) with a repeated key which is completely insecure.

Answer (score 0):

You could either keep treating the ciphertext as bytes (you can store binary files or send binary data over HTTP for instance) or you could encode it to text using base 64 or hexadecimal encoding. Before decryption, you should then of course decode the strings back to the binary ciphertext.